# Issue With Jquery Checkbox with Data Attribute Condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this spinet and let me know why the `if($(this).data('type')=="red"){}` is not working here?

```js
$('input:checkbox[name=data]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).data('type')=="red"){
         if($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert('Red Checkbox Checked');
        }
        else{
              alert('Red Checkbox Un Checked');
        }
    }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-tyep="red">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-tyep="red">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-tyep="red">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-tyep="green">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-tyep="green">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-tyep="green">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-tyep="blue">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-tyep="blue">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-tyep="blue">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-tyep="blue">
```

Comment: What you need is this $(this).attr('data-type')=="red"

Comment: @Pamio Solanky, both work. The mistake is in the html code, see below

Comment: Yep, just saw that. I'm on mobile so couldn't see it all 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled "data-type" in the html code as "data-tyep".

See the following code.

```js
$('input:checkbox[name=data]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).data('type')=="red"){
         if($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert('Red Checkbox Checked');
        }
        else{
              alert('Red Checkbox Un Checked');
        }
    }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-type="red">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-type="red">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-type="red">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-type="green">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-type="green">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-type="green">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-type="blue">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-type="blue">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-type="blue">
<input type="checkbox" name="data" data-type="blue">
```